# How to display the list using viewdata[" "] in the view?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, .net-core, controller

```
    I have to display my details in the list view .I am storing my details in controller using viewdata and i need to use the viewdata in my view .The view part is not working.IN view part i have to use view data inside foreach and iterate through the list .Help me out!!

    Previously i was storing in static list given below:
      public static List<EmployeeModel> staticEmployeeViewModelList = new List<EmployeeModel>();
    my controller part
     public async Task<IActionResult> ImportEmployeeDetails(IFormFile excelfile)
            {
                try
                {

                    EmployeesViewModelList employeesListObject = new EmployeesViewModelList();
                    // var employeesListObject = new EmployeesViewModelList();

                    List<EmployeeModel> employeesViewModelList = new List<EmployeeModel>();

                    if (excelfile == null || excelfile.Length == 0)
                    {
                        return View(employeesListObject);
                    }
                    var supportedTypes = new[] { ".xls", ".xlsx" };
                    var ext = Path.GetExtension(excelfile.FileName);
                    if (!supportedTypes.Contains(ext))
                    {
                        return View(employeesListObject);
                    }
                    var path = Path.Combine(
                               Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot",
                               "EmployeeDetails.xlsx");

                     FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
                    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
                    {
                        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                        int ColCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

                        for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
                        {
                            EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel();
                            // emp.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString());
                            emp.EmpEin = worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();
                            emp.EmpFirstName = worksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString();

                            employeesViewModelList.Add(emp);

                        }
            ViewData["EmployeeList"] = employeesViewModelList;
                        //to get data
          employeesViewModelList = ViewData["EmployeeList"] as List<EmployeeModel>;//convert back to llist
          staticEmployeeViewModelList = employeesViewModelList.ToList();
         ViewData["EmployeeList"] = employeesViewModelList.ToList();
                        employeesListObject.EmpModelList = employeesViewModelList;
                        employeesViewModelList = ViewData["EmployeeList"] as List<EmployeeModel>;

                        // return View(employeesListObject);
                        return View(employeesListObject);

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewData["Message"] = "Opps! Something Went wrong!";
                    return RedirectToAction("ExcelPackage");
                }
        }
    My View:
```

My view 
       // In foreach loop i have used the below code
     @foreach (var employee in (List)TempData["EmployeeList"])
                                {
                                    @foreach(var item in employee.EmpModelList.ToList())
            {
       // the above one is not working 
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
                    Save
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    EmpEin
                                
                                
                                    FirstName
                                
                                
                                    LastName
                                
                                
                                    Email
                                
                                
                                    Country

```
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.EmpModelList.ToList())
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpEin)

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpFirstName)

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpLastName)

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpEmail)

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HomeCountry)

                                </td>
                                <td>

                                <td><a class="edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a></td>

                                <td class="EmpId" style="display:none">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpEin)</td>
                                                           </td>

                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use ViewData in view ,first we have to store the list of properties in controller using an object .As we  need to  bind the model class in the view to get the list properties and we have to use the model directly in view .

```
@using ECOLAB.SIP.Web.XXXXXX @*(model folder)*@
@model ECOLAB.SIP.Web.Models.XXXXXXX @*(class name inside the model folder)*@
```

after that we have to implement like below

```
var emplist = ViewData['List'] @*(name should match with the controller)*@

var list=emplist as employeemodel @*(this is my model class name)*@
foreach(var item in list)

{
<li>@item.EmployeeName</li>

}
```